# pgfplot fixed point iteration

Tags: pgfplots

How can I plot the iteration part of fixed point iteration? I can plot the function g(x) and y=x but the iteration part (as shown in the picture), do we need to do manually for each point?

[image]

Comment: No. Here it's one way to plot it: www.aprendematematicas.org.mx/metodo-del-punto-fijo-codigo-latex2e/

Comment: What you try? Please, show us! Use of the `intersections` library may help you.